# How can I refresh a lightning component

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a lightning record form which i want to refresh after I create records. By default, after I click save, it holds the values which I entered. I tried setting the recordid fields to null but it just sets the fields as empty and the buttons are still invisible. Currently, I am having to reload the entire page. Is there any way to refresh that specific lightning record form component? I have a handler for onsuccess.

Answer (score 0):

To reset the form, you can use [reset()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/documentation) method available for record-edit-form.

```
handleReset(event) {
   const inputFields = this.template.querySelectorAll(
       'lightning-input-field'
   );
   if (inputFields) {
       inputFields.forEach(field => {
           field.reset();
       });
   }
}
```

you can call this method from onsuccess handler as well.

Comment: I am using the lightning-record-form. I have tried nulling out the record id after success, but that just clears the fields, which makes the buttons inactive. What I want is to refresh the component to its fresh state

Comment: Can you add the code which you tried in your question?